I cant get the pixel color when I click assembly 8086
so Im trying to write a code that a part of it is getting the pixel color when I left click
here is the code:
proc mouse_click
mov ax,0h ;resets the mouse
int 33h
mov ax,1h ;shows the mouse
int 33h

not_pressed:
mov ax,3h
int 33h
cmp bx, 1       ;checks if left key is pressed
jne not_pressed

shr cx, 1 ;devide the x coordinates in 2 to get correct x coordinates
mov [left_pressed_x], cx  ;moves x cordinates to left_pressed_x when left button is pressed
mov [left_pressed_y], dx  ;moves y cordinates to left_pressed_y when left button is pressed         
        
mov bh, 0      ;sets page to zero   
mov ah, 0Dh    ; checks pixel color in mouse coordinates(left_pressed_x, left_pressed_y) 
int 010h                       ; al = color
mov [left_pressed_color], al   ;  moves the color to left_pressed_color     
cmp [left_pressed_color], 01h  ;checks if color in (left_pressed_x, left_pressed_y) coordinates is green
je text_mode                   ; jumps to text mode label that switches from graphic mode to text mode (for testing, currently not working)             
ret

endp mouse_click
I know I need to use ah = 0dh int 10h, but its still not working and I cant see where I got it wrong.
Im expecting the code to turn into text mode when I click on the green color, but it just does nothing(the text mode is just for testing).

Please correct the formatting in your question. Apply code fences (3 backtick characters) around the assembly snippet.
